# Transfer iPad games to external hard drive?

Tags: ipad, data-transfer, games

I have a 16gb iPad 2. Most of the space is taken up by games and it's hard figuring out what games I want to remove to open up space. Is there a way to transfer the games wirelessly to an external hard drive? I know on Android, you can transfer games to a micro sd card. Not sure if it's possible on an iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

No, unless the device is jailbroken. Without jailbreaking, the applications can't be transferred elsewhere and remain useable.

Comment: Could you elaborate, why is it that way, what makes it not useable?

Comment: @Buscar No-one but Apple can answer the 'why is it that way' but Apple have never wanted filesystem interaction on iOS. It's not useable because the files are external to the default location and can't be executed.

Comment: heh, that's what I thought.  oh well.  I'll just remove games I don't play that often.  considering buying a 64gb ipad when I have enough money.  that's the advantage of android tablets and smartphones: storage space is expandable and transferable, really versatile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) to backup your data to your mac/pc. [image]

Note: This does not transfer your data. 
If you want to transfer your data too, select everything and and save it to your mac/pc[image]

Next, when you want to use the app, re install it through iFunbox, delete the old content and copy the data you saved to your mac back into the file in your mac. 
(This is a very troublesome and long method) 
A alternative is [iUSBport by hyper](http://www.hypershop.com/HyperDrive/iUSBport-Mini/), but I don't have it and am not sure if it works.